# How do I turn off DBUG level logging in BayeuxServer (embedded in Jetty)?

Tags: java, logging, jetty, cometd, bayeux

When running the CometD Bayeux implementation in Jetty (7.1.5), lots of `DBUG` level logging is output to the console. I've identified the logger as a `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog` instance, but I'm not sure how to configure it.

I'm using Jetty embedded within another application, so I tried the things suggested at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging ("With Jetty embedded" section), but had no success.

At the moment I'm running my app with `|& grep -v DBUG`, but that's fairly annoying. Does anyone know how to configure this type of logger?

Answer (score 2):

Finally tracked down how to set the debug level. Where the `CometdServlet` is created and added to a context, you can set the `logLevel` init parameter on the `ServletHolder` to an appropriate level (anything 3 or greater includes debug).

```
ServletHolder comet = context.addServlet( CometdServlet.class, "/cometd/*" );
comet.setInitParameter( "logLevel", 2 );
```